# A power is a limit over what diagram?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

A product in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a limit over a diagram $F:S\to \mathcal{C}$ where $S$ is a set and is to be viewed as a discrete category.

I am struggling to see how a power $x^k$ of an object $x\in \mathcal{C}$ is to be defined in this way. Do we take $S$ to have $k$ identical objects? But then isn't $S$ just a one-object category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The category $S$ is a discrete category with $k$ different objects.  The functor $F$ then sends all of these objects to the same object $x$ of $\mathcal{C}$.  So the objects of $S$ aren't identical, they just get identified by $F$.

Comment: Ah, so the effect of the functor has to be mentioned when defining limits in this way. I thought that once we say the source category has $k$ objects then immediately I should think of a "diagram" as $k$ different objects in the target category. Thanks for clarifying this admittedly embarrassing misunderstanding.